# `collectAsState` doesn't collect the latest value when emitted from the viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Resource definition for reference

```
sealed class Resource<T>(open val data: T?) {
    class Success<T>(override val data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Failure<T>(val message: String) : Resource<T>(null)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>(null)
}
```

In my HomeScreen composable, employeeResource is sometimes an instance of Failure

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel, navController: NavController) {
    val employeeResource = viewModel.userResource.collectAsState().value
```

To confirm which instance of failure it is, I print out a log message when it is an instance of Failure from the HomeScreen composable like so:

```
if (employeeResource is Resource.Failure) {
    Log.e(TAG, "HomeScreen: ${employeeResource.message}")
}
```

Now, the problem is that I only emit a Failure instance in the init block of the MainVIewModel

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val username = repository.getLoggedInUser()
        if (username == null) {
            userResource.emit(Resource.Failure("THIS WAS CALLED"))
        } else {
            userResource.emit(repository.getEmployeeByUsername(username))
        }
    }
}
```

and the MainViewModel is instantiated when the MainActivity and the first page is always the LoginScreen as opposed to the HomeScreen

in order to go from the LoginScreen to the HomeScreen, the LoginButton calls this

```
LoginButton {
    viewModel.authenticate(username, password) {
        isAuthenticationError = !it
        if (it) {
            navController.popBackStack()
            navController.navigate(HOME_SCREEN)
        }
    }
}
```

which as you can see is a call to a function in the viewModel defined as this:

```
fun authenticate(username: String, password: String, onAuthenticationFinish: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.authenticateUser(username, password) {
            if (it) {
                if (repository.getLoggedInUser() == null) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("how did u manage to log in without saving the user's username?")
                }

                viewModelScope.launch {
                    val employeeResource = repository.getEmployeeByUsername(username)
                    userResource.emit(employeeResource)
                }
            }
            onAuthenticationFinish(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Now if u look closely into the inner viewModelScope.launch { } block, I always emit a non-Failure

1. viewModel instantiates, initiates viewModel.userResource with a Failure instance
2. LoginScreen is the screen currently on display
3. User clicks on log in with correct credentials
4. viewModel.authenticate() emits a new value which is NOT a Failure
5. LoginScreen navigates to HomeScreen
6. HomeScreen retrieves viewModel.userResource as state

why is this happening?

I expect the Home Screen to `collect` the `Success` element that I `emit` from `viewModel.authenticate`. This causes the following issue:

[image]